# RxJS: Rate limit and concurrently limit HTTP requests made at different places

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I am writing a script using an external API that needs to limit the requests based on:

- a maximum number of requests per second
- a maximum of current requests

I found and achieved have this behavior working for a single request, but I have a workflow where I need to:

- deal with pagination
- make two different kind of requests to the same API, the second one being dependent of the first one.

The snippet below illustrates the requests workflow, I tried several things with the `mergeMap` and `expand` `concurrent` parameters and some techniques I found here that has I said work well for one request but I am a little bit confused on how to track all the requests to "sync" the limits across all the requests.

```
 * Get a page of 1000 companies and the total number of companies.
 *
 * @param afterId Optional id of the last fetched company (to get the next ones).
 */
function getCompanies(afterId?: string): Observable<{ count: number; companies: Company[] }> {
  const options = { limit: 1000, afterId }
  return this.http.post('https://example.com/searches/companies', options)
}

function getAllCompanies(): Observable<Company[]> {
  let alreadyFetchedCount = 0
  this.getCompanies().pipe(
    expand(({ count, companies }) =>
      count <= alreadyFetchedCount ? EMPTY : this.getCompanies(companies[companies.length - 1].uuid)
    ),
    tap(({ companies }) => (alreadyFetchedCount += companies.length))
  )
}

/**
 * Get a page of 1000 funding rounds.
 *
 * @param companyUuid The funding rounds company uuid.
 * @param afterId Optional id of the last fetched company (to get the next ones).
 */
function getFundingRounds(
  companyUuid: string,
  afterId?: string
): Observable<{ count: number; fundingRounds: FundingRound[] }> {
  const options = { limit: 1000, companyUuid, afterId }
  return this.http.post('https://example.com/searches/companies', options)
}

function getAllFundingRounds(companyUuid: string): Observable<FundingRound[]> {
  let alreadyFetchedCount = 0
  this.getFundingRounds().pipe(
    expand(({ count, fundingrounds }) =>
      count <= alreadyFetchedCount ? EMPTY : this.getFundingRounds(fundingrounds[fundingrounds.length - 1].uuid)
    ),
    tap(({ fundingrounds }) => (alreadyFetchedCount += fundingrounds.length)),
    reduce((acc, value) => [...acc, ...value], [])
  )
}

function main() {
  getAllCompanies().pipe(
    // Here I get a stream of 1000 or less companies until all companies have been fetched.
    // Let's work one company by one company.
    mergeMap((companies) => companies),
    // For each company, get the funding rounds and return the company extended with them.
    mergeMap((company) =>
      getAllFundingRounds(company.uuid).pipe(map((fundingRounds) => ({ ...company, fundingRounds })))
    ),
    toArray(),
    tap(companies =>
      // Do something with the result
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: Do you just want to delay the requests  ? and why are you using mergeMap twice ?

Comment: I need to be sure not to make more than:
1. X requests per second
2. Y requests in parallel

My problem is that the requests are fired from various places and I don't know how I could keep track of all of them to apply these limits.

In my complete script I do other operations and I just kept this structure, I'll edit the example to make it clearer.


EDIT: Afterthought I think two mergeMap make the code easier to understand. The first one transforms a stream of array into a stream of elements and the second one merge one observable per element.

Comment: `My problem is that the requests are fired from various places` - which requests? also, isn't the `main` function where you 'centralize' everything? I suppose that you want to apply the backpressure logic there, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `delay` that will make sure that you are making http requests within specified time and `concatMap` that will help you make requests in sequence

```
this.function1().pipe(
  mergeAll(),
  delay(1000),
  concatMap((data: any) => this.function2(data.id)),
).subscribe(
  console.log
);

function2(id: string = ''): Observable<any> {
console.log('id', id);
return serviceCAll().pipe(
  delay(1000)
 );
}
```